# How to get a list of employees available in particular time in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of employees. Which has columns like (EmpId(int), AvailableFrom (Time), AvailableTo(Time)).
          I need to get list of employees available on a particular time (8:15:00 to 9:30:00).
         I have written a query like this.

```
Select * from employees emp where
(emp.availablefrom<'09:30:00.0000000' and
emp.availableto>'08:15:00.0000000')
```

But in the result list I am also getting the employees who are available from (9:00:00 to 10:00:00).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your records match your predicate. from 09:00 is indeed smaller than 09:30 and to 10:00 is indeed larger than 08:15.

Comment: how time is  stored in the table? as 12 hours format or in 24 hours format?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   employees emp 
WHERE 
       emp.availablefrom >= '08:15:00.0000000' 
   AND emp.availablefrom <= '09:30:00.0000000'
   AND emp.availableto   >= '08:15:00.0000000' 
   AND emp.availableto   <= '09:30:00.0000000'
```

Comment: Proberbly the use of `between`makes the code more legible.

Comment: Thank you.But,It is giving the results of only of 8:15 to 9:15, but It should also give the employees whose time is from 8:00 to 16:00 or 8:00 to 10:00.

Comment: @reporter: maybe, but i wanted to use `>=` (as opposed to OP's `>`) to show that i'm including the start- and end-times whereas OP was excluding it before. That might nott cause his issue but it might be important anyway.

Comment: @reporter, If I use > only, it is showing zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your comparisons, like `emp.availablefrom>'08:15:00.0000000'` and
`emp.availableto<'09:30:00.0000000'`.

Comment: It is giving zero results.

Comment: Sorry, guess I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187922.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   employees emp 
WHERE (emp.availablefrom between  '08:15:00.0000000' and '09:30:00.0000000')
and (emp.availableto between '08:15:00.0000000'  and '09:30:00.0000000')
```

Comment: It is not showing the results, whose timing is 8:00 to 16:00. And also showing the results like 9:00 to 10:30 (This should not show, becoz the employee is available from 9:00, but I need employees available between 8:15 to 9:30).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from employees emp where (emp.AvailableFrom<='08:15:00.0000000' and emp.AvailableTo>='09:30:00.0000000')
```

Thank you Guys..I just got the required result, using above query..